# recommendation for a php validation framework

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

I'm validating allot of fields now in PHP, and I have to preform basic (string length ect.) and more complex (strip <> tags, for example)

Can anyone recommend a class that does this, or maybe a framework, or maybe some functions that do these things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're validating POSTed forms: use [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) and [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html)

Comment: For modularity, Zend is a winner.

Comment: Couldn't recommend Zend_Form any more strongly, see http://pastebin.com/m3a0b3857 for an example of how easy adding validators and filters is

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP >= 5.2.0 then you can use PHP's built in [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php). In particular, have a look at [filter_var_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php), which you can use to validate an array of inputs, each with its own validation rules. If you don't want to buy in to a complete framework then these might prove useful.

Alternatively, I've found [Kohana's validation library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation) to be very good.

Answer (score 1):

Just see [php validation class](http://www.maheshchari.com/60-validation-functions-with-php/) ,it has over 60 validation methods with in single php class.

Answer (score 1):

[Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

The most awesome validation engine ever created for PHP.

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

$number = 123;
v::numeric()->validate($number); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ace: http://code.google.com/p/phpv/

Small, cool, easily extensible and what's more: I developed it! :)

It's context agnostic too and one can use it for validation in CLI scripts as well.

Also it uses namespaces which have FINALLY been added to the language. So no more name collisions and all that sh*t.

Cheers